# ConfigurationManager looking for different files on different systems

Tags: c#, winforms, configuration-files, configurationmanager

I'm using configuration manager in the simplest way:

Read:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Foo"]
```

Write:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["Foo"].Value = value;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

The problem is that after installing the application on different machines - some are looking for the file: "My.Application.exe.config"
while others look for "My.Application.config" (same, w/o the ".exe")

Another interesting detail is that after installing VS on the problematic machines - it works ok.

And my question is: Ah?!!?
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you connect behaviour <- Windows version?

Comment: Guessing. But if it works after installing VS can it be something that got fixed in .NET3.5 SP1 ?

Edit - Found a MS Connect page about this issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/290821/configurationmanager-openexeconfiguration-misbehaves-on-some-platforms

Comment: Thanks... It feels good when you have someone to blame...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, your links were very helpful.
Since this is a .NET issue (as described in the links above), I tackled it from a different angle than suggested:
Since my configuration file is vast and demands both read and write operations, i'm using a special class to handle it - `configurationFileHelper`.

What I did was adding a static constructor to this class, in which i'm inquiring the expected name for the file, and, if necessary, renaming the existing file to match it:

```
    static configurationFileHelper()
    {
        try
        {
            string fullFilename = Application.ProductName + ".exe.config";
            string expectedFilename = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath;
            if (!File.Exists(expectedFilename) && (File.Exists(fullFilename))
                    File.Move(fullFilename, expectedFilename);
        }
        catch { ; }
    }
```

Hope this is helpful to someone...